# Dependent Probability (Without Replacement)

Tags: probability, statistics

I've got a two part question relating to some probabilities: There's three events A = 4/19, B = 6/19, C = 9/19 (say we being with 19 total cell phones, and they're being returned to a store. A, B, C are the reasons they were returned.)

1) What is the probability that all three were returned for the same reason. Here I was thinking, since there's no mention of replacement, that [(6 C 3)(4 C 3)(9 C 3)]/ (19 C 3) would make sense, but I'm not quite sure.

And...

2) What's the probability that they were returned for different reasons. Once again, I was thinking of doing P(ABC)'= 1 - (A U B U C) but I think that gives me a number > 1, so that doesn't make much sense.

Thanks for the help

Comment: First, we need to be clear where these "three phones" came from that we are asking for the probability of.  Do we have a store who had precisely nineteen phones returned, four of which for reason $A$, six of which for reason $B$, etc... and we are taking three of those nineteen phones?  If so, remember when it is appropriate to *add* instead of multiply numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes sorry, I should've been more specific. There were 19 to begin with and three are being randomly selected and returned. And I'm looking for the probability of them being returned for the same reason. Ah so for the first part I would need to add the numerator, right?

Comment: Thank you for responding and clearing that up.  You should include the clarification as an edit in your question as well so that people aren't required to read the comments to understand the problem statement.  Yes, by adding the numerator to the first attempt instead of multiplying you will receive a correct answer.

Comment: For the second part of the question, can you please clarify the phrase "*they were returned for different reasons*."  Is that to say that of the three phones returned, exactly one was for reason $A$, one for reason $B$, and one for reason $C$?  Or is that to say that they were not all the same, so two being returned for reason $A$ and one for reason $B$ would still count?

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for the help! And yes they're being returned exactly for one reason each (one for A, one for B and one for C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may temporarily assume that each cellphone returned was labeled with a case# or serial# so that we can distinguish between them.

> This allows us to form an equiprobable sample space which allows us to use counting techniques to find probabilities.

Assuming that our three randomly selected cellphones from those returned were selected from the nineteen without replacement (*which is a more than safe assumption*) we have for the first part

$Pr(\text{all three for same reason})=Pr(\text{all three for reason}~A)+Pr(\text{all three for reason}~B)+Pr(\text{all three for reason}~C)$

The reason why we can add like this is because for all three to have been returned for the same reason *exactly one* of those will be true, either that they were all for reason $A$, or all for reason $B$, etc...

Now, to calculate for example $Pr(\text{all three for reason}~A)$, we count how many ways we can choose three of the cellphones returned for reason $A$ and divide by the number of ways we can select three cellphones regardless of what reason they were returned for.  This gives a probability of $Pr(\text{all three for reason}~A)=\frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{19}{3}}$.  Similarly we calculate the other probabilities as $\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{19}{3}}$ and $\frac{\binom{9}{3}}{\binom{19}{3}}$ respectively.

> We could have made the assumption that the cellphones were drawn from the pool one at a time in sequence, leading to the calculation $Pr(\text{all three for reason}~A)=Pr(\text{first was}~A)\cdot Pr(\text{second was}~A\mid \text{first was}~A)\cdot Pr(\text{third was}~A\mid\text{first two were}~A)=\frac{4}{19}\cdot\frac{3}{18}\cdot\frac{2}{17}$.  This of course gives the same answer as before and might be simpler in some cases to think in this way, however for the second part of the problem we will have an easier time having thought of them being taken simultaneously.

This leads to our final answer for part $1$ being:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{3}+\binom{6}{3}+\binom{9}{3}}{\binom{19}{3}}$$

For part 2, we count how many ways we can select exactly one of the phones from reason $A$, exactly one of the phones from reason $B$, and exactly one of the phones from reason $C$ and divide by the number of ways that we can choose three phones regardless of reason (*selections made simultaneously*).

Approaching via multiplication principle, we have four choices for reason $A$, six choices for reason $B$, and nine for reason $C$ so there are $4\cdot 6\cdot 9$ possible collections of three phones, each reason for being returned being represented.

We have then the answer for the second part:

$$\frac{4\cdot 6\cdot 9}{\binom{19}{3}}$$

Comment: NIce explanation!

Comment: awesome, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @JMoravitz hey sorry but just to be safe I'll ask but for part 2, what's the intuition behind the returns of the phones being dependent (like in this case:  4⋅6⋅9/(19 C 3)) vs being independent. So there being some sort of replacement of phones, and having to "re-return" them?

Comment: I don't follow your question.  If you really are asking about dependence vs independence, we have to be clear.  "Dependence of *what*?"  If I were to assume that the phones were taken in sequence instead of simultaneously, we can define $A_1$ to be the event that the first phone was returned for reason $A$ and we can define $A_2$ to be the even that the second phone was returned for reason $A$.  In that case, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are indeed *dependent* events, not independent.  This can be seen by direct calculation, or intuitively since having one fewer phone for $A$, the chances will change.

Comment: @dejz if you are asking why I recommended taking the cellphones simultaneously versus in sequence (*which does not have anything to do with dependence/independence*), it cleans up calculations considerably.  If you were to take them in sequence, for part two we could have six different cases that we have to calculate!  (*if we aren't careful about how we phrase things.  granted, the calculations will be almost identical*).  We could have had an $A$-phone followed by a $B$-phone followed by a $C$-phone, or we could have had a $B$-phone followed by an $A$-phone followed by a $C$, etc...

Comment: @dejz in the end, however, since the question makes no mention of the order mattering in the property we are looking at (*in this case, all being returned for different reasons*), both methods (*simultaneous or separately in sequence*) will both be correct and produce the same answers.  This can be explained more formally using the shepherd's principle.

Comment: @JMoravitz that clears things up quite a bit, thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65815/discussion-between-dejz-and-jmoravitz).

Answer (score 0):

OK! For part 2 it should be:

$$\frac{{4 \choose 1} \cdot {6 \choose 1} \cdot {9 \choose 1}}{{19} \choose 3}$$

For part 1, you were close, but you should *add* the probability of all phones being returned for reason $A$, the probability of all phones being returned for reason $B$, and the probability of all being returned for reason $C$:

$$\frac{4 \choose 3}{19 \choose 3} + \frac{6 \choose 3}{19 \choose 3} + \frac{9 \choose 3}{19 \choose 3}$$

Comment: thanks a lot! this really helped!

Comment: @dejz Sure ... sorry I misunderstood the problem initially!